# 401(k) profit sharing contribution

Tags: income-tax

I am not contributing to my 401(k) in 2019 due to my retirement on 04/15/2019.  My employer is not contributing either.  This is to allow me to contribute funds to an IRA for 2019 as non taxable.

Since a dividend has been posted to my account in 2019 - does that mean I am considered as participating in the 401(k) for 2019?

Answer (score 6):

If that dividend is from  the already existing investments, then it isn't a contribution.

Any dividends or capital gains that are generated within the 401K, are not counted as a contribution.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't count, but it doesn't matter - you can *always* contribute to an IRA, it's not related to if you contribute to 401(k) or not.

See IRS website https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits:

> **Can I contribute to an IRA if I participate in a retirement plan at work?**
>
> You can contribute to a traditional or Roth IRA whether or not you participate > in another retirement plan through your employer or
>   business. However, you might not be able to deduct all of your
>   traditional IRA contributions if you or your spouse participates in
>   another retirement plan at work. Roth IRA contributions might be
>   limited if your income exceeds a certain level.

Comment: There's no income limit, if he doesn't participate in a 401(k) during the year.  So no, it's not unrelated, and contributing to a 401(k) does not make things better.